# BM01 2011/12 Question 6 Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

6. Let $ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle. The feet of the altitudes from
   $A,B$ and $C$ are $D, E$ and $F$ respectively. Prove that $DE +DF \le BC$
   and determine the triangles for which equality holds.
   The altitude from A is the line through A which is perpendicular to
   BC. The foot of this altitude is the point D where it meets BC. The
   other altitudes are similarly defined.

Thanks in advance for any contributions.

Comment: Did you mean $DE +DF \ge BC$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Delta DEF$ is the orthic triangle of $\Delta ABC$, and it is well-known that $DF=b\cos B$ and $DE=c\cos C$. Also using the well-known projection formulae, $a=b\cos C+c\cos B$. So the inequality is equivalent to:
$$b\cos B + c\cos C \le b\cos C+c\cos B$$
$$(b-c)(\cos B - \cos C) \le 0$$

This inequality is easily proved because $b\le c \implies \sin B \le \sin C \implies \cos B \ge \cos C$. Similar procedure applies for the $b \ge c$ case.

The equality clearly holds in isosceles triangles. $A,B,C$ and $a,b,c$ have usual meaning.

For info on orthic triangle, click [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthicTriangle.html)

Comment: Many thanks. Do you think perhaps though there is another solution? I had made some progress in fashioning a cyclic quadrilateral with its base as the diameter of its circumcircle and the BMO1 does not tend to demand any theorems that are not taught at secondary school.

Comment: Can you tell me what all you know? I'll try to use only that

Comment: http://www.ukmt.org.uk/docs/BMO%20Preparation%20Sheet.pdf Here is what they state is satisfactory to know for the tests. As you can see the requirements for BMO1 are very basic, e.g. alternate angle theorem, opposite angle theorem. It does mention that you should know some properties of orthic circles for the BMO2 and it may well be the case that since this is the hardest question on the paper they require a bit extra knowledge. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: @MadChickenMan , So should I or should I not think of something else?

Comment: It's up to you, it seems unlikely that what you gave wouldn't be the solution, but I am curious as to whether there is another solution. If you think that your solution is probably the only one then don't bother.

Comment: @MadChickenMan well I thought of 2 more ways, but they just turned out to be longer ways to get to what I already had done. In the end of both, I obtained the same inequality that I wrote in the answer. I think any solution would most probably boil down to this. 

And since you're new here, I should probably mention that it is customary here to click on the check mark next to an answer which satisfactorily answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So did these 2 solutions involve the orthic triangle properties used in your first answer, or were you able to find a solution without them, if so I'd love to see them.